# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null. (FormBuilder Package)

Tags: forms, flutter, dart

Guys I'm having this error and I already saw that there are others questions about this same error, but mine is different, because I'm using flutter_form_builder package and I'm using a GlobalKey and it is not declared under build. Actually I know where is causing it, but doesn't know hot to fix it.

The problem happens by using FormBuilder's validators. When it's static it works perfectly. But in my case, I'm using the same form to create as well as to edit an object. Then I need to check which one I'm using to set the validators I need, because when while editing it won't be always I'll need to edit the password. But if will, I also need to make validations to those info the user is writing...

I'll put here the code of this context here to make it better to understand.

```
final List<String Function(dynamic)> _passwordValidators = [
  FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: strings.requiredMsg),
  FormBuilderValidators.minLength(6, errorText: strings.passwordMinLength),
  FormBuilderValidators.maxLength(40, errorText: strings.passwordMaxLength),
];

final List<String Function(dynamic)> _confPasswordValidators = [
  FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: strings.requiredMsg),
  FormBuilderValidators.minLength(6, errorText: strings.passwordMinLength),
  FormBuilderValidators.maxLength(40, errorText: strings.passwordMaxLength),
      (val){
    if( val != _formKey.currentState.fields["password"]
        .currentState.value) {
      return strings.passwordMatch;
    }
    return null;
  }
];

final List<String Function(dynamic)> _emptyPassword = [ ];
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: FormBuilderTextField(
            attribute: "conf_password",
            controller: _confPasswordController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: strings.confPassword,
              counter: SizedBox(),
            ),
            validators: _customerId != null
                ? _confPasswordController.text.isEmpty ? _emptyPassword
                : _confPasswordValidators
                : _confPasswordValidators
          ),
        ),
```

I'd appreciate any help or better approach to get it fixed.
I've already opened an issue in its GitHub repo. Any answer I have I'll post here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error by myself and discovered that it was a setState that was set in the button method. So then it set the form key to null before verifying the key. Now I moved this setState to after the verification so the error faded away.